# Getting Syntax error in this python code, how to eleminate?

Tags: amibroker

////// section begins /* use this afl when buy is different from cover and sell is different from short */ RequestTimedRefresh( 1, onlyvisible = False ) ; _SECTION_BEGIN( "Algoji.com intraday.afl" ); intra = ParamToggle( "Activate Intraday Mode", "NO|YES" ); per10 = Param( "Trade Entry From(HHMM)", 920, 900, 2300, 1 ); per11 = Param( "Trade Entry Upto(HHMM)", 1445, 900, 2300, 1 ); per12 = Param( "Trade Exit(HHMM)", 1515, 900, 2300, 100 ); pop= ParamToggle( "Percentage or Points", "Points|Percentage"); slp = Param( "StopLoss", 0, 0, 1000, 0.1 ); tsl= Param("Trail Stop", 0, 0, 1000, 0.1); tgtp = Param( "Target", 0, 0, 1000, 0.1 ); Col = ParamColor( "Color of Modified Signals", colorYellow ); delay= ParamToggle("Trade Intrabar?", "YES|Candle Completion"); dlong= ParamToggle("Disable Long?", "NO|YES"); dshort= ParamToggle("Disable Short?", "NO|YES"); if(dlong){Buy=Sell=0;} if(dshort){Short=Cover=0;} dd= DaysSince1900(); d=prof= 0; if(delay) {Buy=Ref(Buy,-1); Sell=Ref(Sell,-1); Short= Ref(Short,-1); Cover= Ref(Cover,-1);} qt= Param("Trade Quantity", 0, 0, 1000000) ; exposure= Param("Exposure", 0, 0, 1000000) ; if(exposure>0) qt= round(exposure/ValueWhen(Day()!=Ref(Day(),-1), C)); maxl= Param("Qty using SL (MaxLoss)",0,0,100000 ); if(maxl>0 AND !pop) qt= round(maxl/slp); if(maxl>0 AND pop) { basicprice= LastValue(ValueWhen(Day()!=Ref(Day(),-1), C)); sl= slp*basicprice/100; qt= round(maxl/sl); } intraex = intra AND (TimeNum() > per12 * 100); intraen = !intra OR ( TimeNum() <= per11 * 100 AND TimeNum() >= per10 * 100 ); Buy1 = Buy; Sell1 = Sell; Short1 = Short; Cover1 = Cover; Buy=Sell=Short=Cover=0; bflag = sflag = sp=bp = 0; slarr = tgtarr = qtarr= Null; for ( i = 10; i < BarCount; i++ ) { if ( ( Cover1[i] OR intraex[i]OR( H[i] > slarr[i-1] AND (sl>0 OR tsl>0) ) OR ( L[i] < tgtarr[i-1] AND tgt > 0 ) ) AND sflag ) { Cover[i] = 1; CoverPrice[i]= C[i]; sflag = 0; d= dd[i]; prof= sp-C[i]; } if ( ( Sell1[i] OR intraex[i] OR( L[i] < slarr[i-1] AND (sl>0 OR tsl>0) ) OR ( H[i] > tgtarr[i-1] AND tgt > 0 ) ) AND bflag ) { Sell[i] = 1; SellPrice[i]= C[i]; bflag = 0; d= dd[i]; prof= C[i]- bp; } if ( Buy1[i] AND intraen[i] AND bflag == 0 ) { Buy[i] = 1; bflag = 1;         bp= C[i];       sl=slp; tgt= tgtp;      if(pop)         {sl= slp*bp/100;        tgt= tgtp*bp/100;} if ( slp ) slarr[i] = bp-sl; if ( tgtp ) tgtarr[i] = bp+tgt; } if ( bflag AND Buy[i]==0 ) { slarr[i] = slarr[i-1]; tgtarr[i] = tgtarr[i-1]; if(tsl>0 AND pop) slarr[i] = Max(slarr[i-1], H[i]*(1-tsl/100)); if(tsl>0 AND !pop) slarr[i] = Max(slarr[i-1], H[i]-tsl); } if ( Short1[i] AND intraen[i] AND sflag == 0 ) { Short[i] = 1; sflag = 1; Sp= C[i]; sl= slp; tgt= tgtp;       if(pop)         {sl= slp*Sp/100;        tgt= tgtp*Sp/100;} if ( slp ) slarr[i] = sp + sl; if ( tgtp ) tgtarr[i] = sp - tgt; } if ( sflag AND Short[i] == 0 ) { slarr[i] = slarr[i-1]; tgtarr[i] = tgtarr[i-1]; if(tsl>0 AND pop) slarr[i] = Min(slarr[i-1], L[i]*(1+tsl/100)); if(tsl>0 AND !pop) slarr[i] = Min(slarr[i-1], L[i]+tsl); } } Plot( slarr, "SL", Col, styleThick ); Plot( tgtarr, "TGT", Col, styleThick ); PlotShapes( IIf( Buy, shapeUpArrow, shapeNone ), Col, 0, H, Offset = 15 ); PlotShapes( IIf( Short, shapeDownArrow, shapeNone ), Col, 0, L, Offset = 15 ); PlotShapes( IIf( Cover, shapeStar, shapeNone ), Col, 0, H, Offset = -25 ); PlotShapes( IIf( Sell, shapeStar, shapeNone ), Col, 0, L, Offset = -25 ); sig = IIf( BarsSince( Buy ) < BarsSince( Short ), 1, 0 ); messageboard = ParamToggle( "Message Board", "Show|Hide", 1 ); if ( messageboard == 1 ) { GfxSelectFont( "Tahoma", 13, 100 ); GfxSetBkMode( 1 ); GfxSetTextColor( colorWhite ); GfxSelectSolidBrush( colorDarkTeal ); // this is the box background color pxHeight = Status( "pxchartheight" ) ; xx = Status( "pxchartwidth" ); Left = 1100; width = 310; x = 5; x2 = 310; y = pxHeight; GfxSelectPen( colorGreen, 1 ); // broader color GfxRoundRect( x, y - 160, x2, y , 7, 7 ) ; GfxTextOut( ""+WriteIf(intra, "Intraday Mode Activated", "Intraday Mode Not Activated" ), 13, y-160 ); GfxTextOut( ( "Current Qty "+qt ), 13, y-140 ); GfxTextOut( ( "Last" + " Signal came " + ( BarsSince( Buy OR Short ) ) * Interval() / 60 + " mins ago" ), 13, y - 120 ) ; // The text format location GfxTextOut( ( "" + WriteIf( sig == 1, "BUY @ " + ValueWhen(Buy,C) , "SHORT @ " + ValueWhen(Short,C) ) ), 13, y - 100 ); GfxTextOut( "Stop Loss : " + WriteIf(slp==0, "Not Activated", ""+slarr), 13, y - 80 ); GfxTextOut( "Target : " + WriteIf(tgtp==0, "Not Activated", ""+tgtarr), 13, y - 60 ); GfxTextOut( ( "Current P/L : " + WriteVal( IIf( sig == 1, (C-ValueWhen(Buy,C))*qt, (ValueWhen(Short,C)-C)*qt ), 2.2 ) ), 13, y-40 ); // GfxTextOut( ( "jhjh " ), 13, y-20 ); } //section begins for auto trade instr= ParamList("Instrument Name","EQ|FUTIDX|FUTSTK|OPTIDX|OPTSTK|FUTCOM"); stag= ParamStr("Strategy Tag", "STG1"); qty= NumToStr(qt[BarCount-1], 1.0, False) ; bp= sp= NumToStr(Close[BarCount-1],1.2, False); if(dlong){Buy=Sell=0;} if(dshort){Short=Cover=0;} if(delay) {Buy=Ref(Buy,-1); Sell=Ref(Sell,-1); Short= Ref(Short,-1); Cover= Ref(Cover,-1);} global algoji; algoji = Name() + NumToStr( Interval() / 60, 1.0, False ) ; procedure aStaticVarSet( SName, Svalue ) { global algoji; StaticVarSet( Sname + algoji, Svalue ); } function aStaticVarGet( SName ) { global algoji; Var = StaticVarGet( Sname + algoji ); if ( IsNull( Var = StaticVarGet( Sname + algoji ) ) ) Var = 0; return Var; } sym = Name(); //_TRACE("t"+t); Checkdt=Nz(aStaticVarGet("lastdt")); dt = LastValue( DateTime() ); Checkdtss=Nz(aStaticVarGet("lastdtss")); dtss = LastValue( DateTime() ); Checkdtc=Nz(aStaticVarGet("lastdtc")); dtc = LastValue( DateTime() ); Checkdts=Nz(aStaticVarGet("lastdts")); dts = LastValue( DateTime() ); RTBuy = LastValue( Buy) AND Checkdt != dt; RTShort = LastValue( Short) AND Checkdtss != dtss; RTCover = LastValue( Cover) AND Checkdtc != dtc; RTSell = LastValue( Sell) AND Checkdts != dts; if ( RTCover ) {      aStaticVarSet("lastdtc",dtc );      StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 ); _TRACE( "#"+Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+",SX,"+sym+",,," +bp +","+qty+","+instr+",,");    Algoji_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "SX",sym,"M","",bp,qty,instr,stag); } if ( RTSell ) {   aStaticVarSet("lastdts",dts );      StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 ); _TRACE( "#"+Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+",LX,"+sym+",,," +sp +","+qty+",,,");     Algoji_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "LX",sym,"M","",sp,qty,instr,stag); } if ( RTBuy ) {    aStaticVarSet("lastdt",dt );    StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 ); _TRACE( "#"+Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+",LE,"+sym+",,," +bp +","+qty+","+instr+",,");    Algoji_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "LE",sym,"M","",bp,qty,instr,stag); } if ( RTShort ) {      aStaticVarSet("lastdtss",dtss );    StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 ); sp= NumToStr(Close[BarCount-1],1.2, False); _TRACE( "#"+Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+",SE,"+sym+",,," +sp +","+qty+","+instr+",,");    Algoji_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "SE",sym,"M","",bp,qty,instr,stag); } Button = ParamToggle( "Enable Button Trading", "YES|NO" ); expiry= ParamStr("Expiry",""); strike= ParamStr("Strike",""); type= ParamStr("Option Type", ""); sym = Name()+ "|"+expiry+ "|" +strike+ "|" +type; function GetSecondNum() { Time = Now( 4 ); Seconds = int( Time % 100 ); Minutes = int( Time / 100 % 100 ); Hours = int( Time / 10000 % 100 ); SecondNum = int( Hours * 60 * 60 + Minutes * 60 + Seconds ); return SecondNum; } function PopupWindowEx( popupID, bodytext, captiontext, timeout, left, top ) { displayText = bodytext + captiontext; if ( ( StaticVarGetText( "prevPopup" + popupID ) != displayText) OR ( StaticVarGet( "prevPopupTime" + popupID ) < GetSecondNum() ) ) { StaticVarSetText( "prevPopup" + popupID, displayText); StaticVarSet( "prevPopupTime" + popupID, GetSecondNum() + timeout ); PopupWindow( bodytext, Captiontext + popupID, timeout, Left, top ); } } x1= Status( "pxchartleft" )+10; y1= Status( "pxcharttop" )+20; if ( Button == 0 ) { click = GetCursorMouseButtons() == 9; Px = GetCursorXPosition( 1 ); Py = GetCursorYPosition( 1 ); x2 = x1 + 60; y2 = y1 + 60; GfxSelectSolidBrush( ColorRGB( 0, 102, 0 ) ); //buy GfxSelectFont( "Tahoma", 13, 100 ); GfxSetBkMode( 1 ); GfxSetTextColor( colorWhite ); GfxRoundRect( x1, y1, x2, y2 , 7, 7 ) ; GfxTextOut( "LE", x1 + 20, y1 + 20 ); sx1 = x2; sy1 = y1; sx2 = sx1 + 60; sy2 = sy1 + 60; GfxSelectSolidBrush( ColorRGB( 255, 204, 204 ) );//sell GfxRoundRect( sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2 , 7, 7 ) ; GfxSetTextColor( ColorRGB( 153, 0, 0 ) ); GfxTextOut( "SE", sx1 + 20, sy1 + 20 ); ex1 = x1; ey1 = y1+60; ex2 = ex1 + 60; ey2 = ey1 + 60; GfxSelectSolidBrush( ColorRGB( 255, 204, 204 ) );//sell GfxRoundRect( ex1, ey1, ex2, ey2 , 7, 7 ) ; GfxSetTextColor( ColorRGB( 153, 0, 0 ) ); GfxTextOut( "LX", ex1 + 20, ey1 + 20 ); GfxSelectSolidBrush( ColorRGB( 0, 102, 0 ) );//sell GfxRoundRect( ex2, ey1, ex2+60, ey2 , 7, 7 ) ; GfxSetTextColor( colorWhite ); GfxTextOut( "SX", ex2 + 20, ey1 + 20 ); if ( px > x1 AND pxy1 AND py < y2 AND Click ) { _TRACE( "# ," + NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False) + ", BUY triggered from button, " );        AlertIf( 1, "SOUND C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav", "Audio alert", 1, 2, 1 ); StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 );    PopupWindowEx( "ID:1", "BUY", "Buy Triggered from Button "+Name(), 1, -1, -1 );     AlgoJi_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "LE",sym,"M","",sp,qty,instr,stag);    } //https://algoji.com/ if ( px > sx1 AND pxsy1 AND py < sy2 AND Click ) { _TRACE( "# ," + NumToStr( DateTime(), formatDateTime ) + ", SHORT triggered from button, " );        AlertIf( 2, "SOUND C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav", "Audio alert", 2, 2, 1 ); StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 );    PopupWindowEx( "ID:3", "SHORT", "Short Triggered from Button "+Name(), 1, -1, -1 );     AlgoJi_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "SE",sym,"M","",sp,qty,instr,stag); } //https://algoji.com/ if ( px > ex1 AND pxey1 AND py<ey2 AND Click ) { _TRACE( "# ," + NumToStr( DateTime(), formatDateTime ) + ", SELL triggered from button, " );      AlertIf( 3, "SOUND C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav", "Audio alert", 2, 2, 1 ); StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 );    PopupWindowEx( "ID:3", "SELL", "Sell Triggered from Button "+Name(), 1, -1, -1 );   AlgoJi_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "LX",sym,"M","",sp,qty,instr,stag); } //https://algoji.com/ if ( px > ex2 AND px<(ex2+60) AND py>ey1 AND py < ey2 AND Click ) { _TRACE( "# ," + NumToStr( DateTime(), formatDateTime ) + ", Cover triggered from button, " );      AlertIf( 4, "SOUND C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav", "Audio alert", 2, 2, 1 ); StaticVarSet("counter", Nz(StaticVarGet("counter"))+1 );    PopupWindowEx( "ID:3", "Cover", "Cover Triggered from Button "+Name(), 1, -1, -1 );     AlgoJi_Signal(NumToStr(Nz(StaticVarGet("counter")),0,False), "SX",sym,"M","",sp,qty,instr,stag); } }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code as it improves readability.

Comment: _"Getting Syntax error in this python code"_ That's not Python code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a Python, it is AFL. It will be much easier if you post it as a code.
If you run it in AFL Formula Editor it will help you to debug it - simply click "Apply" and you will have all errors highlined.
I've found that you missed some "*" in your formula.